# Wordpress Gutenberg custom columns block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, acf-gutenberg

I'm trying to create a custom "columns" block for Gutenberg with ACF & Wordpress, so what I want is a easy to manage columns block, where user can input some number representating the amount of wanted columns (for example, 5) and a for will create that columns.

All worked as well, since I've tried to create multiple innerblocks... My code started this way:

```php
acf_register_block_type([
    'name' => "theme-columns",
    'title' => __("Columns", "mytheme"),
    'description' => __("Columns", "mytheme"),
    'category' => "theme-blocks",
    'icon' => "grid-view",
    'render_callback' => [$this->renderers, "columns_renderer"],
    'mode' => "preview",
    'supports' => [
        'align' => true,
        'mode' => false,
        'jsx' => true
    ],
    'enqueue_assets' => function(){
        wp_enqueue_style("bootstrap");
    }
]);
```

And the `columns_renderer` function:

```php
public function columns_renderer()
{
    $count = get_field("columns-count");
    ?>
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-xl-5 justify-content-center">
        <?php for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++): ?>
        <div class="col">
            <InnerBlocks />
        </div>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

So, as (not) expected, it's not working because Gutenberg doesn't support multiple `<InnerBlocks />` per block... Searching on the web, I've found some people talking about doing this like `core/column` block does, using some "hacks"... But I can't undestand what to do...

Can someone help me and give me some way to reach what I need?

Thank you!

-- UPDATE --

Tried to creating a "column" block and settings "columns" to only accept newly created "column" block, but still not working...

```php
public function column()
{
    $this->register_block([
        'name' => "theme-column",
        'title' => __("Column", "mytheme"),
        'description' => __("Column", "mytheme"),
        'category' => "theme-blocks",
        'icon' => "columns",
        'render_callback' => [$this->renderers, "column_renderer"],
        'mode' => "preview",
        'supports' => [
            'align' => true,
            'mode' => false,
            'jsx' => true
        ],
        'enqueue_assets' => function(){
            wp_enqueue_style("theme-main");
        }
    ]);
}
```

```php
public function column_renderer()
{
    ?>
    <InnerBlocks />
    <?php
}
```

```php
public function columns()
{
    $this->register_block([
        'name' => "theme-columns",
        'title' => __("Columns", "mytheme"),
        'description' => __("Columns", "mytheme"),
        'category' => "theme-blocks",
        'icon' => "columns",
        'render_callback' => [$this->renderers, "columns_renderer"],
        'mode' => "preview",
        'supports' => [
            'align' => true,
            'mode' => false,
            'jsx' => true
        ],
        'enqueue_assets' => function(){
            wp_enqueue_style("theme-main");
        }
    ]);
}
```

```php
public function columns_renderer()
{
    $allowedBlocks = ["acf/theme-column"];
    $template = array(
        array('acf/biore-column', []),
    );
    $column_count = get_field("columns-count");
    ?>
    <div class="row py-4">
        <?php for($i = 0; $i < $column_count; $i++): ?>
        <div class="col">
            <InnerBlocks allowedBlocks="<?= esc_attr(wp_json_encode($allowedBlocks)); ?>" template="<?= esc_attr(wp_json_encode($template)); ?>" />
        </div>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: were you able to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I've actually been doing something very similar, although I am stuck on a different issue now.

It looks like you are still trying to create multiple `InnerBlocks` in your `columns_renderer` function. Instead, what I do is I create one `InnerBlocks` and fill it with a `$template` made up of multiple `Column` blocks.

I use `templateLock="all"` on the `Row` `InnerBlocks` to stop any new blocks being added there, something similar could also be achieved by using `allowedBlocks` depending on if you want to be able to add more `Columns` from the visual editor or not. I add `templateLock="false"` to the `Columns` `InnerBlocks` in order to overwrite the parent (`Row`) value and allow content to be added into it.

I use `acf` to create a `cols` field with a numeric range slider for the `Row` block, default value is `1` to create 1 column. As you move the slider, more `Columns` will be added.

Setting up the blocks:

```
acf_register_block_type(array(
  'name'                => 'row',
  'title'               => 'Row',
  'description'         => 'A row content block.',
  'category'            => 'formatting',
  'mode'                => 'preview',
  'supports'            => array(
    'align'             => true,
    'anchor'            => true,
    'customClassName'   => true,
    'mode'              => false,
    'jsx'               => true
  ),
  'render_callback' => 'block_row',
));

acf_register_block_type(array(
  'name'                => 'column',
  'title'               => 'Column',
  'description'         => 'A column content block.',
  'category'            => 'formatting',
  'mode'                => 'preview',
  'supports'            => array(
    'align'             => true,
    'anchor'            => true,
    'customClassName'   => true,
    'mode'              => false,
    'jsx'               => true,
  ),
  'render_callback' => 'block_col',
));
```

Outputting the `Row` content:

```
function block_row( $block ){
    $classes = '';
    if( !empty( $block['className'] ) ) {
        $classes .= sprintf( ' %s', $block['className'] );
    }
    if( !empty( $block['align'] ) ) {
        $classes .= sprintf( ' align%s', $block['align'] );
    }

    $cols = get_field('cols');
    if( empty( $cols ) ) {
        $cols = 1;
    }

    for( $x = 0; $x < $cols; $x++ ) {
        $template[] = array( 'acf/column' );
    }
?>
<div class="row-block row <?php echo esc_attr($classes); ?>">
    <h1>Row</h1>
    <?php 
    echo '<InnerBlocks template="' . esc_attr( wp_json_encode( $template ) ) . '" templateLock="all"/>';
    ?>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Outputting the `Column` block:

```
function block_col( $block ){
    $classes = '';
    if( !empty( $block['className'] ) ) {
        $classes .= sprintf( ' %s', $block['className'] );
    }
    if( !empty( $block['align'] ) ) {
        $classes .= sprintf( ' align%s', $block['align'] );
    }

    $template = array( array( 'core/paragraph', array(
            'content' => 'Enter content here',
        ) ) );
?>
<div class="col-block <?php echo esc_attr($classes); ?>">
    <h1>Col</h1>
    <?php 
    echo '<InnerBlocks template="' . esc_attr( wp_json_encode( $template ) ) . '" templateLock="false"/>';
    ?>
</div>
<?php
}
```